# Can iOS use different filtering parameters for different texture units in the same context?

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

In iOS, I have an input image, which I am rendering to an intermediate texture (using a framebuffer) and then rendering that texture to the iOS-supplied renderbuffer (also using a framebuffer, of course). This is 2D, so I'm just drawing a quad each time.

No matter what I've tried, I can't seem to get the second rendering operation to use GL_LINEAR on the texture (I'm using GL_NEAREST on the first). The only way I've seen something filtered is if both textures use GL_LINEAR. Extremely similar code (at least, the OpenGL bits) works fine on Android. Am I just doing something wrong, or does this not work on iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "yes, you can use different filtering options with different texture units in the same context". I had different issues with my program.